# Mutate If Instance duplicate

Tags: r, if-statement, duplicates, dplyr

I got a table (of schools) which is made by data about the pupils, type of school etc. plus x- and y-Coordinates. I want to create a Map showing all the schools. But some schools having two or more different schooltypes at the same adress. So the x- and y- are the same and I cant show both at the map because the Markers are at the exact location. Now I want to change the x-coordinate (X_CO) of one of the multiple sets of coordinates a little bit.

My task is to find a way to select one instance of a pair of duplicates and mutate the row "X_CO":

if first (or last) duplicate==TRUE then `mutate(dat$X_CO=dat$X_CO+0.00015)`. Else no changes. And this for every instance of the table. And repeat for cases with more than two Instances with the same Coordinates.

Ive tried `duplicated(dat$X_CO)` but this gives me a TRUE to both Name_B and Name_D. Any suggestions would be aprreciated :)

```
Data_have <- data.frame(
    Name = c("Name_A","Name_B","Name_C","Name_D"),
    X_CO = c(8.456,8.456,9.876,8.456)
)

Data_want <- data.frame(
    Name = c("Name_A","Name_B","Name_C","Name_D"),
    X_CO = c(8.456,8.457,9.876,8.458)
)
```

Comment: There are no duplicates in the example you shared. How did the number change for `Name_B`?

Comment: The "duplicate" is in the column "X_CO". Its not the complete row. The change is what I want.

Comment: So `have$X_CO[duplicated(have$X_CO)] <- have$X_CO[duplicated(have$X_CO)] + 0.00015`?

Comment: Yes, but the ```duplicated(have$X_CO)``` gave me TRUE for Name_A and Name_B.

Comment: No It should give TRUE only for the second name...I get `duplicated(have$X_CO)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE`. I added an answer. Have a look

Comment: Youre right, my fault. Im checking my data again... Some schools having three (or more?) school types. So I would need to repeat this task. Until I find no duplicates anymore.

Comment: Ok have a look at the answer now and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alter the last duplicate, i.e. `c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3)` to become `c(1, 2, 3, 3.00015, 3.00030)`, then (and changing your example a bit),

```
    Name  X_CO
1 Name_A 8.456
2 Name_B 8.456
3 Name_C 8.456
4 Name_D 8.456
5 Name_E 8.456
6 Name_F 9.876


i1 <- duplicated(have$X_CO)
vec_to_add <- 0.00015 * seq(sum(i1))

have$X_CO[i1] <- have$X_CO[i1] + vec_to_add
```

which gives,

> ```
>     Name    X_CO
> 1 Name_A 8.45600
> 2 Name_B 8.45615
> 3 Name_C 8.45630
> 4 Name_D 8.45645
> 5 Name_E 8.45660
> 6 Name_F 9.87600
> ```

Based on your comment we can use `ave` to group all consecutive duplicates, i.e.

```
have$new.X_CO <- have$X_CO + ave(have$X_CO, have$X_CO, FUN = function(i)0.00015 * (seq(length(i))-1))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     Name  X_CO new.X_CO
> 1 Name_A 8.456  8.45600
> 2 Name_B 8.456  8.45615
> 3 Name_C 8.456  8.45630
> 4 Name_D 8.456  8.45645
> 5 Name_E 8.456  8.45660
> 6 Name_F 9.876  9.87600
> 7 Name_G 7.000  7.00000
> 8 Name_H 7.000  7.00015
> 9 Name_I 7.000  7.00030
> ```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. One Problem left: I got 1325 duplicates. So as I can see it, the seq(sum(i1)) gives me very high numbers for the last entries or very low numbers for the first entries. If it could start counting at every set of duplicates. That would solve it completly. I dont know how to tell R to restart counting.

Comment: @JulianSchulz Please have a look now. If you are satisfy please accept (check tick mark) so we can consider closed

Comment: Ive deleted a comment I made before I could see @Sotos latest answer.